# Removed firebase array being re-added automatically

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a cocktail app where users can save, delete recipes. The saving part is fine, its the delete I am having some trouble with. The issue is that when I delete the object I want to using the arrayRemove() in the firestore, the deleted object gets re-added after being deleted for a second. But sometimes the object is deleted for good. As you can imagine, I wanna clear this issue and make sure the object I removed from the array, stays removed. The code from the component that fetches the content and deletes the content is as follows. Can anyone see why this might be so?

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Col, Row, Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import NavBar from '../NavBar/NavBar';
import Footer from '../Footer/Footer';
import './SavedCocktailInstructions.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { CocktailContext } from '../../context/CocktailContext';
import fire from '../../Config/firebase';
import { db } from '../../Config/firebase';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

export default function SavedCocktailInstructions(props) {
    const [ cocktailInformation, setCocktailInformation ] = useState('');
    const nameOfDrink = props.match.params.name;
    const { uid } = useContext(CocktailContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        onAuthStateChange();
    }, []);

    function onAuthStateChange() {
        return fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            if (user) {
                let userId = user.uid;
                fetchSavedData(userId);
            } else {
            }
        });
    }

    const fetchSavedData = (uid) => {
        db.collection('users').doc(uid).onSnapshot(function(doc) {
            let recipes = doc.data();
            const chosenCocktail = recipes.array.find((recipe) => recipe.strDrink === nameOfDrink);
            setCocktailInformation(chosenCocktail);
        });
    };

    const {
        strIngredient1,
        strIngredient2,
        strIngredient3,
        strIngredient4,
        strIngredient5,
        strIngredient6,
        strIngredient7,
        strIngredient8,
        strIngredient9,
        strIngredient10,
        strMeasure1,
        strMeasure2,
        strMeasure3,
        strMeasure4,
        strMeasure5,
        strMeasure6,
        strMeasure7,
        strMeasure8,
        strMeasure9,
        strMeasure10,
        strDrinkThumb
    } = cocktailInformation;

    const remove = () => {
        db.collection('users').doc(uid).update({
            array: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(cocktailInformation)
        });
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <NavBar />
            <Container fluid className="SavedCocktailInstructions">
                <Row>
                    <Col xs={12} sm={6} md={6} className="SavedCocktailInstructions-image">
                        <img src={strDrinkThumb} alt="" className="SavedCocktailInstructions-image img-fluid" />
                    </Col>

                    <Col xs={12} sm={6} md={6} className="SavedCocktailInstructions-text">
                        <h1 className="font-style-1 ">{nameOfDrink}</h1>
                        <p>{`Served in a ${cocktailInformation.strGlass}`}</p>
                        <ul className="SavedCocktailInstructions-ul">
                            {strIngredient1 === null ? '' : <li>{`${strIngredient1}-${strMeasure1}`}</li>}
                            {strIngredient2 === null ? '' : <li>{`${strIngredient2}-${strMeasure2}`}</li>}
                            {strIngredient3 === null ? '' : <li>{`${strIngredient3}-${strMeasure3}`}</li>}
                            {strIngredient4 === null ? '' : <li>{`${strIngredient4}-${strMeasure4}`}</li>}
                            {strIngredient5 === null ? '' : <li>{`${strIngredient5}-${strMeasure5}`}</li>}
                            {strIngredient6 === null ? '' : <li>{`${strIngredient6}-${strMeasure6}`}</li>}
                            {strIngredient7 === null ? '' : <li>{`${strIngredient7}-${strMeasure7}`}</li>}
                            {strIngredient8 === null ? '' : <li>{`${strIngredient8}-${strMeasure8}`}</li>}
                            {strIngredient9 === null ? '' : <li>{`${strIngredient9}-${strMeasure9}`}</li>}
                            {strIngredient10 === null ? '' : <li>{`${strIngredient10}-${strMeasure10}`}</li>}
                        </ul>
                        <p>{cocktailInformation.strInstructions}</p>

                        <Link
                            onClick={() => remove(uid)}
                            exact
                            to="/saved"
                            className="SavedCocktailInstructions-remove-button"
                        >
                            Remove from saved?
                        </Link>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Typically if a write operation briefly seems accepted before being reverted, that means the server-side security rules reject the operation. So you might want to check those.

Comment: fair point there mate. the issue is that the removArray function works as it should sometimes, and doesn't do so, the rest of the time. Im trying to isolate the issue with no luck. Have any leads based on this new info?

Comment: Heya @FrankvanPuffelen, this issue is still persisitng and kinda driving me nuts as it the remove works at times and doesn't the rest of the times. To answer your question on security rule mine is as such- match /users/{userId} {
 allow read, write, create: if request.auth.uid == userId;
 }

Comment: I also noticed that when i delete the document(named with the UID of the said user) which contains the array of cocktails recipes saved by the user from the firebase console, it is re-added right back :/

Comment: If you make changes from the Firebase console, it bypasses security rules. If those changes are reverted, you're most likely to have some process running that is listening for the changes and undoes them. This could be the application you're working on, but it can also be some background process, or a Cloud Function.